# Display Data based on User selection from Dropdown menu

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, gridview

I am creating a page.

I have used EF to create classes for my tables.

Table schema is as follows:

[image]

```
AssetCategory has N TO M relationship with the other two tables
```

In my aspx page, I have added a dropdown  box  and used EF to populate  the dropdown  from AssetCAtegaories and populated  all the items from Field Name.

I have added a grid view and bound it to AssetCategoryCodes displaying Jcode.

Now I need to make connection between the two items.

meaning display items in my grid view based on the user selection from dropdown.

Edited

```
MobileAssetCategoryID is Fk in AssetCategoyCodes
MobileAssetCategoryID  is FK in DowntimeReasonCodes

for Instance  in AssetCategories
 if ListItemID =1  and name = Honda 

if ListItemID =2  and name = Toyota


than AsstCategoryCodes   has 

MobileAssetCategory Id=1 , jCode =Accord


MobileAssetCategory Id=1 , jCode =Civic

MobileAssetCategory Id=2 , jCode =Camry

MobileAssetCategory Id=2 , jCode =corolla
```

So My question is  when user selects Honda in the dropdown?

I only want to show Honda vehicles and not everything.

How can I do this ?

Comment: Which field in AssetCategoryCodes links to which field in AssetCategories? the field names really look confusing - relationship doesn't seem very obvious...

Comment: edited to explain the relationship between tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!  it... Here is the Code from  my main.aspx.cs

```
namespace Test
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        EntitiesName DbEntity = new EntitiesName();
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                var name = from c in DbEntity.MobileAssetCategories select new { c.ListItemId, c.Name };
            MainCodes.DataSource= name.ToList();
            MainCodes.DataValueField = "ListItemId";
                MainCodes.DataTextField= "Name";
                MainCodes.DataBind();
                MainCodes.Items.Insert(0,"--Select--");

            }

        }

        protected void MainCodes_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int JCodeId = Convert.ToInt32(MainCodes.SelectedValue.ToString());
            var JCode = from c in DbEntity.MobileAssetCategoryCodes where c.MobileAssetCategoryId.Equals(JCodeId) select new { c.JdeCode };
            JCodeDisplay.DataSource = JCode.ToList();
            JCodeDisplay.DataBind();
            int reasonCode = JCodeId;
            var RCode = from a in DbEntity.MobileAssetDowntimeReasonCodes where a.MobileAssetCategoryId.Equals(reasonCode) select new { a.JdeReasonCode };
            ReasonCode.DataSource = RCode.ToList();
            ReasonCode.DataBind();

        }

        protected void JCodeDisplay_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void ReasonCode_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```